# Can you let a proxy between Client and Server change the Client´s Ip Adress

Tags: java, sockets

I have a **Client** and a **Server** Application. Between the **Client** and the **Server** I have a **Proxy**.

When the **Client** opens the Socket with new Socket(ip,port) it is supposed to **connect to** the **Proxy**. It is doing that without any Problem.

Now I want the **Proxy to connect to the Server**, but the **Server** is **supposed to think**, that it is the **Client** which connects to him.

Any ideas on how I can do that?

Comment: How is the server *supposed to think* ? Originating IP Address ?

Comment: Well the Server blocks you off, when your IP Adress is already registered. So if I use the Proxy it is, when I have 3 Clients open, 3 times the same IP-Adress, so 2 request get blocked off.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on how you are connecting to the server. Is it just a plain socket? If so, it will be hard, at least via normal Socket API, at the end the Proxy is who is connecting to the server...

IF you are accepting http requests, then, depending on the proxy server, you will probably get a header X-Forwarded-For which will have the real IP Address that connected to the proxy.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply.
Yes, I only use a plain simple Socket. I already thought that that would be a problem. Just thought that somebody might know something I didn´t. Nevertheless thanks for the answer.